# Mouseenter/Mouseleave on SVG use and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I'm building my menu's website with SVG picture and I have a probleme with jQuery and the mouseleave event..

This is my HTML / CSS :

```
<div style="display:none;">
    <svg id ="home-icon" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <path  d="M57.0 <!-- .. SVG source Here ... --> 98z"/>
    </svg>
</div>
<ul id="top-menu">
    <li class="menu-icon">
        <svg><use xlink:href="#home-icon" /></svg>
    </li>
</ul>
.menu-icon svg{
    fill: #AB1;
    width:64px;height:64px; 
}
.menu-icon.active svg{
    background: #AB1;
    stroke: #e8e8e8;stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

And the jQuery :

```
$('.menu-icon').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active');
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

[-> Code here <-](http://jsfiddle.net/R9aeu/1/)

But when the mouse is on the svg balise, I have a trigger 'mouseleave' on my li.menu-icon.. I ready don't understand why ?!

Thank you all for reading and help !

Comment: why don't you use the user interaction pseudo-class `:hover`?

Comment: It's a simple example for a more complex code. I use the :hover for the CSS but i need get this informations on jQuery for others actions :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we use `<svg><use ..` we do not actually copy the svg into our container node. So we are actually triggering `mouse out`

See [http://jsfiddle.net/8RCyD/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/8RCyD/2/) - *Updated link from @Erik with up to date version of jquery, solving the cross browser discrepancies discussed, thanks*

We could

```
$(".menu-icon").append("#menu-icon"); /* the svg we want */
```

.. first and then ..

```
$('.menu-icon').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active');
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure in what context you tried it but the link you posted does not work for me, it does have the OP's problem.

Comment: It's work for me with and init loop who clone all svg :
http://jsfiddle.net/R9aeu/4/

Comment: Ahh interesting @KingKing, I will have a look

Comment: @KingKing - fine here Opera 19 ( *its only a jquery hover add class, so why wouldn't it* ). SVG support ? - odd it doesn't work for you.

Comment: @RobSedgwick yes, it's strange, could you try checking the **About** info of your Opera (by Help->About Opera), it shows me that the version is `12.16` and I also tried checking for new update and it showed me that I'm using the latest version.

Comment: Thx all for helping me ! It's work for me, but don't know for svg support ? :/ 
This articles talk about svg browser support : http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/11/27/svg-icons-ftw/

Comment: @CactOos well, looks like Opera does not support `svg`, I don't know why such an old browser doesn't support while the very young browser namely `Maxthon` does support it, and the Rob Sedgwick modified code also works fine in that young browser.

Comment: @KingKing , according to http://caniuse.com/svg, Opera 12 should be fine. I'm on Opera 19.0 here

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8RCyD/2/ didn't work in Opera 12.16 because the used version of jQuery in that example is too old. It works just fine with a newer version of jQuery, see e.g http://jsfiddle.net/8RCyD/5/.

Comment: @ErikDahlström , well spotted. This was the version set in the original and we just forked it. Didn't even see that!

Answer (score 7):

I'm late to the party here, but recently encountered this problem and wasn't interested in over-complicating my jQuery to prevent `mouseleave` when the pointer was over an SVG icon. I found that the CSS property

```
pointer-events: none;
```

can solve this issue if it's applied to the SVG - in fact, the property is part of the SVG recommendation and is specifically intended for similar situations: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Answer (score 0):

Instead of jQuery, you can just use pure CSS:

```
.menu-icon:hover svg {
    background: #AB1;
    stroke: #e8e8e8;
    stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R9aeu/3/)**

Comment: How I say for the King King's reply : " It's a simple example for a more complex code. I use the :hover for the CSS but i need get this informations on jQuery for others actions :/"